# How to get the memory size of a dataType in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to get the memory size of a datatype in Haskell ?

E.g : I have a list of item a, and I want to limit this list to x bytes in memory... I will reject all the next items to add above that threshold...

Comment: What should happen when you "reject"? Raise an error and let the program terminate?

Comment: Let's say if I reach the limit I display the number of elements and terminate the program...

Comment: I would tweak this question slightly. Don't limit one small part of your program; let it grow as much as it wants, but use your OS to limit how much memory the program as a whole can allocate. Then your question becomes "How do I handle an out-of-memory exception in Haskell?"